# Let $X(t) = e^{r(T-t)}/S(t)$. Find the SDE of $X(t)$ provided that $S(t)$ satisfies the BSM model.

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion, differential

This is the last part to a 3 part question! I am nearly done going through the questions I had difficulty with while studying, again, anyone's help would be greatly appreciated!

Let $X(t) = e^{r(T-t)}/S(t)$.

Find the SDE of $X(t)$ provided that $S(t)$ satisfies the BSM model.

Make sure the drift and diffusion terms are expressed in terms of $X(t)$ rather than $S(t)$.

Comment: Well either use the fact that $S_t = S_0 e^{(\mu - \sigma^2/2)t + \sigma W_t}$ and then use ito lemma (deriving wrt to $t$ and $W_t$) or use Ito directly on your expression deriving wrt $t$ and $S_t$ and then use the definition of $S$ to simplify. (Here I guessed that BSM stands for Black Scholes Model)

Comment: Im sorry @Ant i really dont get this

Comment: And yes sorry, BSM is black scholes model @Ant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the function $f(x,t) = \frac {e^{r(T-t)}}{x}$. Then $X = f(t, S)$ and you can use [Ito lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/It%C3%B4%27s_lemma) to say that

$$dX_t = \frac{\partial}{\partial t}f(t,x)\mid_{ t,S} dt + \frac{\partial}{\partial x}f(t,x)\mid_{ t,S} dS_t+\frac 12\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}f(t,x)\mid_{ t,S} d \langle S \rangle _t$$

Which results in

$$dX_t = \frac {-e^{r(T-t)}}{S_t}dt  - \frac {e^{r(T-t)}}{S_t^2} dS_t + \frac {e^{r(T-t)}}{S_t^3} d \langle S \rangle _t$$

Given that $$\frac{dS_t}{S_t} = \mu dt + \sigma dW_t$$, we find

$$d \langle S \rangle_t = \sigma^2 S_t^2 dt$$ and substituting we find

$$dX_t = \frac {-e^{r(T-t)}}{S_t}dt  - \frac {e^{r(T-t)}}{S_t} (\mu dt + \sigma dW_t) + \frac {e^{r(T-t)}}{S_t} \sigma^2 dt$$

Now given that $X_t = \frac {e^{r(T-t)}}{S_t}$ we find 
$$dX_t = -X_t dt - X_t(\mu dt + \sigma dW_t) + X_t \sigma^2 dt$$ or

$$\frac {dX_t}{X_t} = (\sigma^2 - \mu - 1)dt - \sigma dW_t$$